# Using ConcatRelated (VBA by Allen Browne) on an UPDATE query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, concatenation

having an issue translating sql from a SELECT query to an UPDATE query.  Ultimate goal is to get a concatenated list within one cell where one record in one table has 1+ rows with different values in another.  The common example:

| User | JobCode |
| --- | --- |
| UserA | 10 |
| UserA | 100 |
| UserA | 200 |
| UserB | 100 |
| UserC | 200 |
| UserC | 250 |

Becomes:

| User | Job Code |
| --- | --- |
| User A | 10, 100, 200 |
| User B | 100 |
| User C | 200, 250 |

(with ", " as the delimiter)

I've used Allen Browne's [ConcatRelated](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html) with success on a SELECT query, as follows

```
SELECT DOETrainingList.SUI, dbo_vw_EPIC_PRD_EMP_TEMPLATE.USER_ID
, GetList("LNK_TEMPLT_ID", "dbo_vw_EPIC_PRD_EMP_TEMPLATE", "USER_ID = """ & [dbo_vw_EPIC_PRD_EMP_TEMPLATE].[USER_ID] & """","",Chr(13) & Chr(10)) AS TemplateIds
FROM DOETrainingList INNER JOIN dbo_vw_EPIC_PRD_EMP_TEMPLATE ON DOETrainingList.EMPDOT1 = dbo_vw_EPIC_PRD_EMP_TEMPLATE.USER_ID
GROUP BY DOETrainingList.SUI, dbo_vw_EPIC_PRD_EMP_TEMPLATE.USER_ID;
```

(note i changed the function to "GetList")
This returns a datasheet with each row from table DOETrainingList and a new Column TemplateIDs that populate the concatenated list of templates where the dbo_vw_EPIC_PRD_EMP_TEMPLATE.USER_ID matched itself in that same table.  All looks good here.

But I can't seem to get this to work on an UPDATE query.

Here's what I have:

```
UPDATE DOETrainingList INNER JOIN dbo_vw_EPIC_PRD_EMP_TEMPLATE ON DOETrainingList.EMPDOT1 = dbo_vw_EPIC_PRD_EMP_TEMPLATE.USER_ID 
SET DOETrainingList.EMP1110 = GetList("LNK_TEMPLT_ID","dbo_vw_EPIC_PRD_EMP_TEMPLATE","DOETrainingList.EMPDOT1 = """ & dbo_vw_EPIC_PRD_EMP_TEMPLATE.USER_ID & """","",Chr(13) & Chr(10));
```

Running this query I get error "Operation must use an updateable query"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, saving aggregated data is a bad idea, but if you must, consider:

Looks to me like you have fields backwards in the function criteria argument. Also, don't JOIN to dbo_vw_EPIC_PRD_EMP_TEMPLATE in UPDATE action (I expect JOIN not needed in SELECT either).

```
UPDATE DOETrainingList SET EMP1110 = 
GetList("LNK_TEMPLT_ID", "dbo_vw_EPIC_PRD_EMP_TEMPLATE", "USER_ID='" & EMPDOT1 & "'", "", Chr(13) & Chr(10));
```

If ID fields are number type, don't use apostrophe delimiters. Since your SELECT code did not error, presume fields are text type.

Comment: They are string :(
Correct on both fronts it looks like - the JOIN was causing a relation that make it impossible to UPDATE.  I must admit I don't understand why the fields are backwards the way I had it, but updating that criteria to "dbo_vw_EPIC_PRD_EMP_TEMPLATE.USER_ID = """ & EMPDOT1 & """" worked (if reversed, and with no Join, it would ask for the parameter value for USER_ID.  I'm definitely missing a core concept here.) 
Many thanks!

Comment: The function code builds a recordset from arguments passing field and table names as well as criteria to filter. Since USER_ID is field in the passed table, it is static and between quotes. EMPDOT1 provides variable input which is pulled from each record of DOETrainingList and is therefore concatenated. The function executes for each record.